# Skype For Business WSUS Server 2012

Tags: windows-server-2012, wsus, windows-update, lync-2013, skype-for-business-2016

Please forgive me if I don't provide all of the required info for anyone looking to help out, but I'm a junior sys admin just getting started with using and administering WSUS on Server 2012. Basically, I'm looking to locate the update that would upgrade Lync clients to the Skype for business client. From doing some research, it seems the update that upgrades Lync clients to the Skype for business client is KB2889923, but I can't seem to locate it anywhere when searching 'all updates' on the WSUS server for that KB. We currently have Microsoft Office 2010 standard installed on our workstations and then Lync 2013 installed separately.

Oddly enough, I see other updates for Skype for business and Lync, but can't seem to find that one. Not sure if this is related/part of the issue, but when browsing the "all updates" section with the criteria "any except declined" for approval and "any" for the status, it reads 8578 updates of 8929 shown, 8929 total -- I've only approved a few updates so far and haven't declined any, so is it wrong to assume that all 8929 should be showing up?

As far as the the products go that I'm getting updates for in WSUS, the following are selected for office:

- Dictionary Updates for Microsoft IMEs
- New Dictionaries for Microsoft IMEs
- Office 2003
- Office 2007
- Office 2010
- Office 2013

I also have the Skype product selected (Skype>Skype for Windows).

For classifications, I have the following selected:

- Critical Updates
- Definition Updates
- Security Updates
- Service Packs

Sorry for the long post, but really appreciate any help that someone could offer on this!

Comment: I don't think you want to install "Skype for Windows", it is different from "Skype for Business 2015". You might make sure you have the latest service pack for Office 2013 installed on the computers where you want to update to Skype for Business 2015. And and IMHO Skype for Business is terrible and I wish I could keep running Lync 2013 instead.

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question, but I would like to say welcome to Server Fault and congratulations on presenting a coherent and detailed question on the first attempt! (You'd be surprised how hard this seems to be for some).

Comment: I haven't got an in depth answer for you, but have you read the suggestions proposed by MS themselves in this article? https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn951396.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You aren't the only one having this issue with some of the April updates not synchronizing with WSUS on Server 2012 (including KB2889923). The following workaround was [posted](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3058255) by Microsoft and may work for you.

> To work around this problem, use the following method to manually synchronize new updates in WSUS. Repeat these steps for every update category that you want to synchronize.
>
> 1. In the WSUS console, disable updates from synchronizing. To do this, follow these steps:
>
>    - In the navigation pane, expand the  node.
>    - Click the Options node.
>    - In the center pane, click Products and Classifications.
>    - In the Products and Classifications dialog box, click the Classifications tab.
>    - Clear the check box for the classification that you cannot synchronize to WSUS.
> 2. Run synchronization in WSUS. To do this, follow these steps:
>
>    - In the navigation pane, expand the  node.
>    - Click the Synchronizations node.
>    - In the right pane, click Synchronize now.
> 3. In the WSUS console, enable updates for synchronizing. To do this, return to the Classifications tab, and then select the check box for a classification that you want to synchronize.
> 4. Run synchronization in WSUS.
> 5. Repeat steps 1-4 for any other update classification that you want to synchronize, as appropriate.
>
>    - Note You can enable and disable more than one update classification at a time. However, at least one classification most be enabled for WSUS synchronization to occur.
> 6. If System Center 2012 Configuration Manager (ConfigMgr) is present in the system, run synchronization in ConfigMgr.